# How to set timeframe for certain part of indicator in pine script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I want to create an indicator in pine script but I want to have 1 part of the indicator (lets say an EMA) set to 15 minute, and the rest (like pivot points and support/resistance lines) set to what ever the chart is.

I haven't written it yet but just want to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using the [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.

Following example requests the close price from 15 min time frame.

```
//@version=4
study("Example security 1", overlay=true)
ibm_15 = security("NYSE:IBM", "15", close)
plot(ibm_15)
```